# jhipster 4 access entity without login

Tags: jhipster

I want to create a page that users can access without to be logged in e.g. a blog post. I have set up a microservice application (Jhipster 4 with angular 2).

This is the `.yo-rc.json` file from the gateway.

```
{
  "generator-jhipster": {
    "promptValues": {
      "packageName": "com.jhipster.blog",
      "nativeLanguage": "en"
    },
    "jhipsterVersion": "4.4.1",
    "baseName": "gateway",
    "packageName": "com.jhipster.blog",
    "packageFolder": "com/jhipster/blog",
    "serverPort": "8080",
    "authenticationType": "jwt",
    "hibernateCache": "hazelcast",
    "clusteredHttpSession": false,
    "websocket": false,
    "databaseType": "sql",
    "devDatabaseType": "h2Disk",
    "prodDatabaseType": "mysql",
    "searchEngine": false,
    "messageBroker": false,
    "serviceDiscoveryType": "eureka",
    "buildTool": "maven",
    "enableSocialSignIn": false,
    "jwtSecretKey": "c6c434f1cd39a1866adec9aaab7e9fc42d736621",
    "clientFramework": "angular2",
    "useSass": true,
    "clientPackageManager": "yarn",
    "applicationType": "gateway",
    "testFrameworks": [
      "gatling",
      "cucumber",
      "protractor"
    ],
    "jhiPrefix": "jhi",
    "enableTranslation": true,
    "nativeLanguage": "en",
    "languages": [
      "en",
      "sv"
    ]
  }
}
```

In `/gateway/src/main/webapp/app/entities/blog/blog.route.ts` I have removed the role in authorities

```
export const blogRoute: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'blog',
        component: BlogComponent,
        data: {
            authorities: [], <--- REMOVED ROLE
            pageTitle: 'gatewayApp.blog.home.title'
        },
        canActivate: [UserRouteAccessService]
    }, {
        path: 'blog/:id',
        component: BlogDetailComponent,
        data: {
            authorities: [], <--- REMOVED ROLE
            pageTitle: 'gatewayApp.blog.home.title'
        },
        canActivate: [UserRouteAccessService]
    }
];
```

and added the following in `/gateway/src/main/java/se/jh/blog/config/SecurityConfiguration.java`

```
.authorizeRequests()
.antMatchers("/api/blogs").permitAll() <-- Added paths
.antMatchers("/api/blogs/**").permitAll() <-- Added paths
.antMatchers("/api/register").permitAll()
.antMatchers("/api/activate").permitAll()
...
```

But still getting a 401 and access denied when I try to access `localhost:8080/#/blog/1`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Receiving a 401 error means the API endpoint is still secured.  The gateway's SecurityConfiguration only applies to the gateway. and the gateway simply proxies your requests to your microservice.

Your microservice also has its own MicroserviceSecurityConfiguration.java, you should edit this file and set `permitAll()` to the blog API.

Comment: I have added the following in /blog/src/main/java/se/jh/blog/config/MicroserviceSecurityConfiguration.java .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/api/blogs").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/blogs/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated() but I still get the same error. I don't know what I'm doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

blogs != blog

One part is that you're allowing everyone to access "blogs" - but you're trying to get "blog"